# CMD crashes without any error when running Citrix clean up tool

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, citrix, citrix-receiver

I have had a cmd batch file to reset my Citrix receiver:

```bat
@echo off

set /p Choice="Do you want to reset Citrix settings? (y/n)"
if (Choice==y) (goto :RESET) else (exit)

:RESET
start "Citrix reset tool" /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin\CleanUp.exe" /silent -cleanUser
if (%errorlevel%==0) (goto :SUCCESS)  else (goto :ERROR)

:SUCCESS
echo Citrix should be rested by now. You may close this window!
pause
exit

:ERROR
echo Citrix was not successfully reset. Please contact your IT department.
pause
```

It used to work just fine. But today I tried it and it crashes the terminal without any error messages. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what are the possible issues and how I can resolve them.

Comment: Run it without the `@echo off` to verify where it crashes. From first view, I don't see how this simple script can crash anything, unless Windows is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this specific tool, but I'd suggest a) start the batch file from a terminal window not just double clicking and b) remove the /silent switch. Maybe that gets you some output so you can get to the bottom of this.

<strike>Edit: There should ne a ReceiverLogs folder somewhere. Maybe check that out too.</strike>

Comment: I have actually tried that. But running `start "Citrix reset tool" /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin\CleanUp.exe"  -cleanUser` doesn't do anything. no output, no error, nothing!

Comment: I don't know if this an error from pasting it here, but there should be only one blank space between ...exe" and -cleanUser.

Comment: That was my mistake actually!

Comment: OK now it stops Citroix and crashes CMD both!

Answer (score 1):

You have not quite used the right `IF` syntax - drop the brackets around the conditions and use the value of the variables. Your current IF statements both execute the FALSE condition (exit):

```
if %Choice%==y (echo yes) else (echo no)
```

The `start` command launches a new process so isn't returning `errorlevel` of the sub-process for `if SUCCESS/ERROR`. Use `call` if wanting the status code back:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin\CleanUp.exe" /silent -cleanUser
if %errorlevel%==0 (goto :SUCCESS)  else (goto :ERROR)
```

Depending on how you launch your CMD script, use of `exit` can close the calling CMD.EXE so its usually safer to end cmd scripts with:

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

See this [handy guide](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Gee, I don't know why I have made that mistake. But I think it is a side issue.

Comment: I assume you fixed the other IF too, I hope you find the other issue.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can use `choice` to limit `y/n` (insensitive)

**2.** Add the operators `&&(return 0) ||(return non 0)`

**3.** Which item **1.** and **2.** Will result in not needing your `goto:lables`

**4.** You can add the flag `/D`irectory in you start command

---

```bat
@echo off 

choice /m "Do you want to reset Citrix settings?"
if not %errorlevel% == 1 goto=:EOF

start "Citrix reset tool" /b /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin" CleanUp.exe /silent -cleanUser

%__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t 3 /nobreak | echo\Checking the Status of Citrix/CleanUp tool, please wait...

%__AppDir__%tasklist.exe | >nul find/i "CleanUp.exe" && (
     %__AppDir__%timeout.exe -1 | echo=Citrix should be rested by now. You may close this window!
    ) || (
     %__AppDir__%timeout.exe -1 | echo=Citrix was not successfully reset. Please contact your IT department.
    )
```

- Some further reading:

  - **[If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
  - **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**
  - **[Start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html)**
  - **[Choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)**
  - **[Timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)**
  - **[Tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)**
  - **[Echo on | off](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
  - **[Redirections in bat file](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
  - **[Conditional Execution `||` and `&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
  - **[Understanding start, `2>nul`, `cmd`, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. Will dig into this. 